# Test recording tool for Webdriver.IO

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, end-to-end

We are testing Webdriver.IO (https://webdriver.io/) with TypeScript to test if it could be a good framework for automating End-to-End GUI-tests on a Web-application. We have already tried Cypress and TestProject.IO, both of which have test-script recorders either natively built or with plugins or both.

I couldn't find a way to record end-to-end tests with Webdriver.IO - meaning I want to start the recorder, perform some actions (perhaps even validations), stop the recorder and have a script ready to be copy-pasted to VSCode.

So the question: What recorders exist for Webdriver.IO to record my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching I came to the conclusion that, at this point in time, the only available test recorder for WebDriver.io is "[WebdriverIO Exporter for Katalon Recorder][1]" available in Chrome Extensions.

However, Katalon is a commercial product and the recorder is dedicated to Katalon. An open-source recorder is yet to be found.
[1]: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webdriverio-exporter-for/kccnpljpbgjkbjoncfpbmkobhacfekko

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).